# Is it possible to get the time-stamps of remote files through HTTP request?

Tags: c#, http

We need to download the latest version of some xml feed from a 3rd party's website automatically every once in a while, but don't want to download it if there are no changes made to that file(since we already have it). The file goes something like `XXXXX_latest.xml`. Would it be possible to query the file's create date, modified date through HTTP to compare with local ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there is, it's part of the HTTP protocol: [Conditional GETs](http://ruturajv.wordpress.com/2005/12/27/conditional-get-request/)

Answer (score 1):

Other options if server does not support conditional get: HEAD request and GET with RANGE header (may work if comparing portion of the file is enough).